# Understanding BoundaryMeshRegion error

Tags: warning-messages, regions, mesh

I am trying to calculate the difference between two `Cuboid`s:

```
reg1 = Cuboid[{-2.60003*10^4, -2.60003*10^4, -2.60003*10^4}, 
{2.60003*10^4, 2.60003*10^4, 2.60003*10^4}];
reg2 = Cuboid[{-2.6*10^4, -2.6*10^4, -2.6*10^4}, {2.6*10^4, 2.6*10^4, 
    2.6*10^4}];

elettrodi = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2];
```

but I get the error:

> BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: The boundary surface is not closed because
>   the edges Line[{{22,12},{12,6},{17,17},{6,22}}] only come from a
>   single face.

What does it mean and how do I solve this problem?

```
$Version
"11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
```

Comment: Mathematica is better at working with discretized regions. Try to apply `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to `reg1` and `reg2` first.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher it solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, it worked for me too. Quality around edges also improved significantly. You should add it as an answer.